# Why do people keep deleting my answers on this question (and without notifying me)

Tags: discussion, answers

[Are there moral theories that don't care about free will and agency?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/88907/are-there-moral-theories-that-dont-care-about-free-will-and-agency)

I'm really confused. The first time, the answer took some time to write. My answers to this question did not obviously misunderstand the question, and contained no mistakes.

Bizarre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post author did delete their question two times, which automatically deletes the whole thread including its answers. It was reposted later, for the second time now.

Thus, you'll have to address the OP here.

Comment: ha mad, thank you.